# html submit button not calling Shiny server

Tags: html, r, forms, shiny

I an working on a shiny form where user can input their responses on form and after clicking on submit the form save the responses to the database.
I have created form on html and while running shiny i am passing that html to ui part of shinyApp() function.

i am able to render page while running shiny application but once i click on submit after filling my responses i am getting error as "400 bad request".

Page and code for html file:
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="shiny.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Form</title>
  </head>

<body>

    <form action="form.html" method="post">

        <div class="firstDiv">
          <h4>Enter your name *</h4>
          <input type="text" name="nameid" value="" placeholder="Your answer" required>
        </div>

        <div class="secondDiv">
          <h4>Email ID *</h4>
          <input type="email" name="emailid" value="" placeholder="Enter valid email id" required>
        </div>

        <div class="lastDiv">
          <input type="submit" name="save" value="submit">
        </div>


        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

My shiny server app code :

```
server <- function(input,output)

{
       observeEvent(input$save,{

               print('done')

        })
}



shinyApp(ui = htmlTemplate("form.html") , server = server)
```

In shiny server code above statement inside button click "Print('done')" is where i'll perform saving response to database.But i am getting error after clicking on submit button.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Why are you using raw HTML in your project, is there a specific meed to do so? `shiny` has its own internal forms which you can use.

Comment: Yes i am aware of shiny internal form but the html form is required in this case as the form functionality and flexibility is very high and i am new to shiny.

Comment: This might help https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/templates.html

Comment: I have already tried this article but was getting error as                   Error in list2env(vars,parent = globalenv()):                                      attempt to use zero-length variable name.

Comment: @PorkChop could you please help me with how to use the "required" parameter of html input elements and input type email in shiny internal forms as we do in raw html to check validations also a regular expression that i have used for pincode text input as highlighted below in codes:

`code`
<input type="text" name="nameid" value="" placeholder="Your answer" required>
<input type="email" name="emailid" value="" placeholder="Enter valid email id" required>
<input type="text" name="pincodeid" value="" placeholder="Enter 6 digit pin" required pattern="[0-9]{6}" maxlength="6">
`code`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't bind the submit button with shiny input object. You call `input$save` but you didn't create such id. Refer to shiny documentation how to bind html inputs with input object.